# In R reactable how to add png image on cells column

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I would like to add a image (local file) inside the first column of my table with reactable. Bellow is my code: Any help?

```
data <- data.frame(
  Animal = c("beaver", "cow", "wolf", "goat"),
  Body = c(1.35, 465, 36.33, 27.66),
  Brain = c(8.1, 423, 119.5, 115)
)

reactable(data, columns = list(
  Animal = colDef(cell = function(value) {
    # image <- tags$img(src = "img/icons_flags/Africa.png", width = '18px', height = '18px')
    tagList(
      tags$img(src = "img/icons_flags/Africa.png", width = '18px', height = '18px'),
      value
    )
  }),
  Body = colDef(name = "Body (kg)"),
  Brain = colDef(name = "Brain (g)")
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Inline embedded images](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/cookbook/cookbook.html#inline-embedded-images) and using `knitr::image_uri` you could do:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  Animal = c("beaver", "cow", "wolf", "goat"),
  Body = c(1.35, 465, 36.33, 27.66),
  Brain = c(8.1, 423, 119.5, 115)
)

library(reactable)
library(htmltools)

img <- tempdir()
download.file("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png", file.path(img, "logo.png"))

reactable(data, columns = list(
  Animal = colDef(cell = function(value) {
    img_src <- knitr::image_uri(file.path(img, "logo.png"))
    tagList(
      tags$img(src = img_src, width = '18px', height = '18px'),
      value
    )
  }),
  Body = colDef(name = "Body (kg)"),
  Brain = colDef(name = "Brain (g)")
))
```

[image]